# Define the priority in a heap by minimum value instead of maxi

Tags: c++, stl, heap

I'm looking at `stl::priority_queue` from [this site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/) and I realized that if I insert some values in the priority queue such as `8 - 95 - 15 - 30 - 29` , then when I'll use the iterator I will get the output `95 - 30 - 29 - 15 - 8`.

How can I do to get the inverse output?, i.e. from min to max. I think this is because the heap it's setted by default to sort the elements by max to min, but how can I change this?

And if it's possible, I want to store TWO values for each node of the heap.

For example:

```
myHeap.push(<1,2>)
myHeap.push(<1,25>)
myHeap.push(<2,5>)
```

And the order will be determined by the second component of my ordered pair. In this example, the output will be `<1,2>; <1,25>; <2,5>`

**EDIT:**
The priority_queue IS NOT a heap. Sorry for call it heap.

Comment: Can't you just negate the priorities?

Comment: Comparator inverse: `std::priority_queue<int, std::deque<int>, std::greater<int>>`. The storing two values is completely unrelated to the original question, but `std::pair<int,int>` as the element type rather than simply `int` would probably do what you want.

Comment: I have to compare it later, and it will be very confuse

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to store pairs of values and use the second item in the pair for your comparison, it'll probably be easiest to define a class to do the job.

```
class my_pair {
    int a, b;
public:
    my_pair(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}

    // reverse the normal ordering, and base on second item of pair:
    bool operator<(my_pair const &other) const { return other.b < b; }  
};
```

You'll probably need at least a few more members (e.g., to retrieve the values from a `my_pair` object), but that should be enough to create them and put them into a priority_queue.